# The diff command for files with empty content

Tags: linux, shell, diff

If I want to get the difference between the 2 directories, I use the command below:

```
diff -aruN dir1/ dir2/ > dir.patch
```

so the dir.patch file should comprise all differences I want, right?

But if `dir2/` contains a file with empty content, and that file is not existent in `dir1/`, for example,

```
dir1/

dir2/empty_content_file.txt ------ with empty content.
```

Then the diff command will not generate any patch for empty_content_file.txt, but it is a needed file.

Is there any expertise or alternative way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `-N` option, which is added to explicitly treat absent file as empty. `man diff` says :

```
     -N,  --new-file 
              treat absent file as empty
```

Comment: But the diff command never creates the patch without -N option for inexistent files in dir1/, so -N is necessary...

Comment: Well I've tested with or without -N option. Without -N option it does show the existence of a file.

Comment: No, no patch is generated without -N argument for inexistent files in the first directory, it shows "Only in dir2/: empty_content_file.txt".

Comment: I had uploaded the screenshot of the operations you mentioned.

Comment: Okay,  I understand your point. You want new file to be added when applying the patch. I believe there's no better option than using `git diff`.

Comment: Yes, you got it!     The new file (with empty content) should be added while applying the patch, but its patch (of the new file with empty content) is not generated by 'diff -aruN' command !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot below shows the operation of "diff -aru" command for inexistent files in the first directory, a message "Only in xxx" will show.

[image: The diff command without -N option for inexistent files in the first directory.]